# How do i tell how many directories are in this path?

Tags: directory

The path is as follows:
`/usr/lib64/qt3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/home/mj1210/.local/bin:/home/mj1210/bin`

Comment: you can count the colons, then add 1 for the last directory on the line

Comment: `echo "$PATH" | awk -F: '{ print NF }'`

Comment: @X Tian 9? Apparently there should be 7?

Comment: @jordanm beware of dupplicate!

Comment: why not provide a sample input and output, so we know what it is you mean? e.g. /dir1/dir2:/dir3 - do you want to count those as 2 or 3 dirs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is one more than the number of colons.

In awk:

```
echo `awk -F: '{print NF}' <<<"$PATH"`
```

With tr (translate) and wc (word count):

```
echo $((`tr -dc : <<<"$PATH" | wc -c`+1))
```

Comment: So the subdirectories are not included in this count? I thought that after every forward slash we go into a subdirectory of the directory before the forward slash?

Comment: I guess it depends on what exactly you want.     You can count each subdirectory of each path, but it didn't seem like that's what the original question asked for.

Answer (score 1):

Many ways to achieve, here's one way that avoids creating any processes, does it all within `bash`.

```
A=${PATH//[^:]}
echo $((${#A}+1))
```

Example

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/lib64/qt3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/home/mj1210/.local/bin:/home/mj1210/bin
$ A=${PATH//[^:]}
$ echo $((${#A}+1))
9
$
```

Comment: beware, a trailing colon is valid, and inflates your count by 1